# connect database with dataGridView

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

How can I connect my Trgovina.mdf with dataGridView?
I follow [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database) tutorial, but it seems that program doesn't find my database.

Connection string looks like that:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Klemen\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Trgovina\Trgovina\Trgovina.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Everything else is the same as tutorial example.
Error string is `An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'`

Full code looks like [this](http://pastie.org/6112613).

Comment: The connection string used is for SQLServer LocalDB. The error message talks about OleDB. With Sql Server you should work with SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc. Could you post the code where you try to open the database for the first time?

Comment: Oh, ok, with SqlConnection works everything just fine. So I can fill my DataGridView in that way to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you talk about in your question use an Access Database and thus uses the OleDB engine to reach and work with the database. Instead your connection string use the syntax reserved for SQLServer LocalDB.

You should change your objects to `SqlConnection` (instead of `OleDbConnection`), `SqlCommand` (instead of `OleDbCommand`) and so on...

With these changes you should be able to connect to the automatic instance of SqlServer LocalDB. The rest of the tutorial could work or not, depending on what is present in the MDF file used.

Comment: thanks a lot! now it works.
I have just one another question fro you. Is it possible to save changes in dataGridView back to database? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You trying to connect to database `.mdf file`, but you have a wrong provider.

> An `MDF` is a Microsoft SQL Server database not a Jet Database like
>   Access (*.mdb).  You cannot just connect to the flat file and read it.
>   You would need to mount the database in an instance of SQL Server. 
>   You could install SQL Server 2005 Express
>
> [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/e24a766f-a507-4755-9ceb-1ec0fbe70ed5)

**Note:** Just download MS SQL Server 2005 Express or later and you must use the [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) instead of [OLE DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to solve your problem.